How to use output in Group Output geometry node?
I cannot understand how to use Output sockets and Output attributes in Group Output node.
Here is a simplified example of what I'm looking for:

Basically, I have a value computed in Geometry Node. I need this value to be passed further, for example, to another GN.
Update based on comments:
Seems like I don't understand something very important about attributes...
Please explain what I'm doing wrong:
GN1 stores attribute:

GN2 reads:

Cube sits at (0,0,0)
(wrong image, please ignore it)

Here I've tried 2 ways to read attribute: 1) from input geometry
2) from attribute.
Sounds like these are basics and somehow I don't get it.

Last image, Capture Attribute doesn't do anything you can delete it. Issue is, your gn_attr has a float value on each of its vertex, and the Cube node expect a single vector value. You can use an Attribute Statistics but it doesn't make much sense. Also, it would help for you to describe in plain english your expectations with these nodes.

You have at least 2 options to pass attributes from a modifier to the next. As far as I can tell, they are equivalent.
Use Store Named Attribute
Any attribute set will survive and will be accessible in other geometry nodes. So in the second modifier, you'll see a yourAttribute just as you set it.
I'd say this is the best way to do it for most cases. There is no need for the attribute to be accessible outside of the geometry nodes.

Use Group Output
The other option is with the output, as your in example. Any name you give in the modifier tab will be the name of the attribute in the geometry. As before, the attribute yourAttribute is accessible in the next modifier.
As Markus von Broady pointed out, this method can lead to some issue on the domain of the attribute. Its domain is implicit from the modifier tab, whereas the other option let us explicity declare the domain of the attribute inside the nodes.

The only difference I can see between both methods, is that the declaration of the attribute is either hidden inside the geometry nodes or accessible on the modifier tab.

I like the second option. How do I access it?

@AndreiZhytkevich Just as any other attribute. No difference there.

I always advise the first option for newbies, because the 2nd has a pitfall: the domain may be wrong. You need to open the Numbers panel and set the correct domain.

@MarkusvonBroady, hm.. I don't understand why domain. To me the output looks like it doesn't belong to anything within GN, it's like an independent variable (value) which only belongs to the stack of modifiers... and how to use it on both ends (save and read) in the first option?

@AndreiZhytkevich I don't quite understand your question. Writing attributes is done with Store Named Attribute, reading attributes is done with Named Attributes.

Sounds like I don't know some basics about attributes lifecycle. I've updated the question with my failed attempt. Can you please take a look?

@AndreiZhytkevich I'd suggest you to try and find some tutorial on the basics of attributes. I also encourage you to read the official doc, at least the first paragraphs which contain essential informations https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html. Feel free to open other questions about specific things.

@Lutzi: I would not write using the Group Output node (second option) that "Its domain is implicit (...)", because it can be explicitly edited using the "Group" tab opened pressing n in the Geometry Node Editor (what Markus is calling "the Numbers panel", I suppose).
